# exc_bad_access error when trying to use custom UITextField on Swift

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I have a custom UITextFieldClass:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class TextFieldWithImage : UITextField {
    override func leftViewRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: self.frame.height / 4, y: self.frame.height / 4, width: self.frame.height / 2, height: self.frame.height / 2)
    }

    func setIcon(iconCode : String){
        let imageView2 = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: self.frame.height / 4, y: self.frame.height / 4, width: self.frame.height / 2, height: self.frame.height / 2))
        imageView2.fontAwesome(fontAwesome: "f10b")
        self.leftView = imageView2
        self.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
    }
}
```

I set it as Custom Class in Identity Inspector.

Then I bound them as outlets to my View Controller:
https://yadi.sk/i/8KL5gkvTi79qL

Problem: when I launch my app I get an error in my AppDelegate class:
https://yadi.sk/i/ytvRof2Di79zw

Whats wrong with it? Please help me.

**UPDATE:** File FontAwesome.swift

```
//
//  Font-Awesome.swift
//
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Hirohisa Kawasaki. All rights reserved.
//
//  Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
//  of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
//  in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
//  to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
//  copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
//  furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:
//
//  The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
//  all copies or substantial portions of the Software.
//
//  THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
//  IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
//  FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
//  AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
//  LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
//  OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
//  THE SOFTWARE.

import UIKit

protocol UnicodeLiteralConvertible {
    func convertToUnicode() -> String
}

extension String: UnicodeLiteralConvertible {

    func convertToUnicode() -> String {
        let scanner = NSScanner(string: self)
        var _unicode : UInt32 = 0
        if scanner.scanHexInt(&_unicode) {
            return String(UnicodeScalar(_unicode))
        }

        return self
    }
}

extension Int: UnicodeLiteralConvertible {

    func convertToUnicode() -> String {
        return String(UnicodeScalar(self))
    }
}

class FontAwesome {

    struct Static {
        static var token : dispatch_once_t = 0
    }

    class func load() {
        dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
            FontManager.load("FontAwesome")
        }
    }

    class FontManager {

        class func load(fontName: String) {
            if (UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(fontName).count > 0) {
                return
            }

            let fontData = findFontData(fontName)
            registerFontData(fontData)
        }

        class func findFontData(fontName: String) -> NSData {
            let fontURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(fontName, withExtension: "otf")
            if let fontURL = fontURL, let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: fontURL) {
                return data
            }

            fatalError("\(fontName).otf is not found in the main bundle resources.")
        }

        class func registerFontData(fontData: NSData) {

            let provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData(fontData)
            if let font = CGFontCreateWithDataProvider(provider) {
                var error: Unmanaged<CFError>?
                if !CTFontManagerRegisterGraphicsFont(font, &error) {
                    println(error)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Use Font Awesome

extension UIFont {
    class func fontAwesome(#size: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
        FontAwesome.load()

        if let font = UIFont(name: "FontAwesome", size: size) {
            return font
        }
        return UIFont.systemFontOfSize(size)
    }
}

extension String {
    static func fontAwesome(unicode fontAwesome: UnicodeLiteralConvertible) -> String {
        return fontAwesome.convertToUnicode()
    }
}

// UIKit

extension UIImageView {

    func fontAwesome(#fontAwesome: UnicodeLiteralConvertible) {
        let _image = _fontAwesome(fontAwesome: fontAwesome)

        image = _image
    }

    private func _fontAwesome(#fontAwesome: UnicodeLiteralConvertible, color: UIColor = UIColor.blackColor()) -> UIImage {
        let unicode = fontAwesome.convertToUnicode()
        let font = UIFont.fontAwesome(size: frame.height)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(frame.size, false, 0)

        let textSize = unicode.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : font])
        let x = (bounds.width - textSize.width)/2
        let y = (bounds.height - textSize.height)/2
        let textRect = CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: textSize.width, height: textSize.height)

        let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle.defaultParagraphStyle()
        let attributes = [
            NSFontAttributeName: font,
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: color,
            NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: style
        ]
        unicode.drawInRect(textRect, withAttributes: attributes)

        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

        return image
    }

}

extension UIButton {

    func setFontAwesome(#fontAwesome: UnicodeLiteralConvertible, forState state: UIControlState) {
        let title = fontAwesome.convertToUnicode()
        setTitle(title, forState: state)
        let font = UIFont.fontAwesome(size: frame.height - 4) // use 2point to padding
        titleLabel!.font = font
    }

}

public extension UIBarButtonItem {
    convenience init(fontAwesome: String, target: AnyObject?, action: Selector) {
        let title = String.fontAwesome(unicode: fontAwesome)
        self.init(title: title, style: .Plain, target: target, action: action)

        let font = UIFont.fontAwesome(size: 25)
        let attributes = [NSFontAttributeName: font]
        self.setTitleTextAttributes(attributes, forState: .Normal)
    }
}
```

But if I comment string `imageView2.fontAwesome(fontAwesome: "f10b")` the error still exists.

Comment: Could be anything, most likely something else. You need to post the stack trace as text. Also, cut out the `fontAwesome` for now, as this is another extraneous potential source of errors.

Comment: Unfortunately the stack trace is empty

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the constructor of `CGRect` correctly. `CGRect` is a `struct` that has two elements, `origin` and `size`. The correct way to refer to a `CGRect`'s height is.

```
 rect.size.height
```

Also, in `leftViewRectForBounds` you should use the passed `bounds` parameter.

The following playground code illustrates that it is working:

```
import UIKit
import XCPlayground

let view = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 512, 512))
XCPShowView("view", view: view)

class ImageTextField : UITextField {

    override func leftViewRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
        let h = bounds.size.height
        return CGRectMake(h / 4.0, h / 4.0, h / 2.0, h / 2.0)
    }


    func setIcon() {
        let h = self.bounds.size.height / 2.0
        let imgView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, h, h))
        imgView.image = UIImage(named: "dado-2")
        self.leftViewMode = .Always
        self.leftView = imgView
    }
}

let imageTextField = ImageTextField(frame: CGRectMake(30,30, 200, 40))
imageTextField.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
imageTextField.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
imageTextField.text = "  hello world"
imageTextField.setIcon()

view.addSubview(imageTextField)
```

Result:

[image: Screenshot]